# AWS S3 w/ tags, DynamoDB, Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift

I'm comparing cloud storage for a large set of files with certain 'attributes' to query.  Right now it's about 2.5TB of files and growing quickly. I need high throughput writes and queries.  I'll first write the file and attributes to store, then will query to summarize attributes (counts, etc), additionally querying attributes to pull small set of files (by date, name, etc).

I've explored Google Cloud Datastore as a noSQL option, but trying to compare it to AWS services.

One option would be to store files in S3 with 'tags'. I believe you can query these with the REST API, but concerned about performance.  I also have seen suggestions to connect Athena, but not sure if that will pull in the tags and the correct use-case.

The other option would be using something like Dynamo or possibly a large RDS?  Redshift says it's for Petabyte scale, which we're not quite there...

Thoughts on best AWS storage solution? Pricing is a consideration, but more concerned with best solution moving forward.

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to store the files themselves in a database like RDS or Redshift. You should definitely store the files in S3, but you should probably store or copy the metadata somewhere that is more indexable and searchable.

I would suggest setting up a new object trigger in S3 that triggers a Lambda function whenever a new file is uploaded to S3. The Lambda function could take the file location, size, any tags, etc. and insert that metadata into Redshift, DynamoDB, Elastic Search, or an RDS database like Aurora, where you could then perform queries against that metadata. Unless you are talking many millions of files, then the metadata will be fairly small and you probably won't need the scale of Redshift. The exact database you pick to store the metadata will depend on your use case such as the specific queries you want to perform.

Comment: Thanks @mark-b. I considered this ETL approach in current solution with filesystem and mysql w/ indexes.  I guess that's why i liked Google's one-stop cloud datastore :)   I guess AWS doesn't match Google's storage with search layer?

Comment: What Google service are you talking about specifically? This? https://cloud.google.com/datastore/ That would be directly comparable to DynamoDB I believe. You wouldn't want to store the raw files in that Google service either. On google you would want to use this to store the actual files: https://cloud.google.com/storage/ which would compare to Amazon's S3.